# For loop printing characters on same line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have this code here, when I debug it, it prints out the characters on multiple lines but I want them to be on the same line in order to recompose the word inputted. For example, when I debug it inputting the word hello it prints out:

```
h
i
l
l
i
```

how ever I would like to print this: `hilli`. Any idea?? Thanks.

```
var say = prompt("name");

for ( var count = 0; count <= say.length; count++){

var letter = say.charAt(count);

  if (letter == "a" || letter == "e" || letter == "o" || letter == "u"){

  letter = "i";
  }

  console.log(letter);

}
```

Comment: Concat the values into a variable and use `console.log()` just once.

Comment: Even better. Use `RegExp` or regular string replacement to work out the occurrences and print the result. You don't need any `loop` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` *always* outputs each invocation on a line of its own.

If you want a single line, you'll have to coalesce the characters into a new string, and then output that after the loop.

For your particular code, you could also just use a regexp to do the whole thing.

```
name = name.replace(/[aeou]/gi, 'i');   // 'g' for global, 'i' for case-insensitive
```

or for case-sensitive:

```
name = name.replace(/[aeou]/g, 'i').replace(/[AEOU]/g, 'I');
```

There might be better ways of writing that last version, but the above is quick and self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally made it. However, could you please explain this ----name.replace(/[aeou]/g, 'i')---- to me.

Comment: It just means "replace every character (`/g`) in the set `[aeou]` with the letter `i`.